# How wordpress core include search.php with $_GET['s']?

Tags: url-rewriting, core

I want to include `custom_search.php` when there is `$_GET['my_s']`.

As you know, if we type on a search field, WordPress core includes `search.php` file because WP Core get $_GET['s'] as query var.

How wordpress do like this?
If possible, I want to see the code lines.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Are you trying to replace the built in search? Add a new search?

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, I want to make a new custom search process.

Comment: search.php is a template for displaying the results, it shouldn't be doing any other work. If you want to dsplay the results differently, modify search.php. If you want to change the search behaviour, use filters and actions.